# Multiple instances of a bean of one class filled with values from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, dynamic-properties

I intend to write some `HealtCheckContributors` for a Spring Boot application using *spring-boot-actuator*. Hence, I implemented two of them. they are intended for checking the health of different apps, of course, but have a nearly identical structure, except the configuration properties, ...

SonarQube complains about that and I wonder if it is possible to have a single health check class but instantiated as many times as defined in `application.properties`.
An example:

`application.properties`:

```
# actuator
app1.management.baseUrl=http://localhost:10000
app1.management.name=app1HealthCheckContributor
app2.management.basUrl=http://localhost:10001
app2.management.name=app2HealthCheckContributor
```

`HealthCheckContributor` for app1:

```java
@Slf4j
@Component("xxx")
public class App1HealthCheckContributor extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    private final App1Properties app1Properties;

    public App1HealthCheckContributor(final App1Properties app1Properties) {
        this.app1Properties = app1Properties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) {...}
}
```

...and this code for each `HealthCheckContributor` only distinct in its *appXProperties*.

Isn't it possible to have some kind of base class like:

```java
@Slf4j
@Component()
public class MyHealthCheckContributor extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    private final MyProperties myProperties;

    public MyHealthCheckContributor(final MyProperties myProperties) {
        this.myProperties = myProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) {...}
}
```

and let Spring Boot take care of instantiating two `HealthCheckContributors` (in our case `App1HealthCheckContributor` and `App2HealthCheckContributor`)?
This would eliminate code duplication.

An example of the properties class file:

```java
@Slf4j
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app1.management")
public class App1Properties {
    private String baseUrl;
    private String ...;
}
```

How can I achieve this and how must an `application.properties` file looks like to achieve what I intend to do?

The final question: [How to test multiple instance creation of a bean of one class filled with values from application.properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69620134/how-to-test-multiple-instance-creation-of-a-bean-of-one-class-filled-with-values)

Comment: Is the logic in `doHealthCheck` method of `App1HealthCheckContributor` and `MyHealthCheckContributor` exactly the same so that you can have a single class covering both use cases?

Comment: Yes, the logic is equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code in `doHealthCheck` is exactly the same for all apps to be checked you could do the following.

You would start by creating a single health check class:

```java
@Slf4j
public class AppHealthCheckContributor extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    private final AppProperties appProperties;

    public App1HealthCheckContributor(final AppProperties appProperties) {
        this.appProperties = appProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) {...}
}
```

And the properties model as follows:

```java
@Slf4j
@Data
public class AppProperties {
    private String baseUrl;
    private String name;
}
```

This means that the configuration would be something like the following (in `application.yml`):

```yaml
health-check:
  apps:
    - baseUrl: http://localhost:10000
      name: app1
    - baseUrl: http://localhost:10001
      name: app2
```

Finally, you would need to create a bean for each app and register them in the application context:

```java
@Slf4j
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "health-check")
public class AllAppPropertiesConfiguration {
    private List<AppProperties> apps;

    @Autowired
    private GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        for (AppProperties app : apps) {
            applicationContext.registerBean(app.getName(), AppHealthCheckContributor.class, app);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, João. How could I test that the contributors are generated and registered in the Spring Boot context?

Comment: You would need to add an `application-test.yml` configuration and use `test` profile in your `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: I already did but accessing the configuration always results in a NPE.

Comment: Then I would suggest you create an additional question and include all your code and tests. Share the link in a comment. Thanks!

Comment: I did so. You can find the link at the end of my original question. Furthermore I found this article about avoiding @PostConstruct:https://levelup.gitconnected.com/stop-using-postconstruct-in-your-java-applications-2a66fb202cb8 
What do you think about?

Comment: I get it and I agree if this is a regular Service or something similar. But this is a configuration class, you will never reuse it and most likely you will not test it directly. Nevertheless, you can always try the constructor approach.

Comment: Instantiating the health check indicators this way prevent me from setting @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator annotation, right? I think I a allowed to put exactly only ONE indicator but not @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator(aaa,bbb,ccc). Hence, I can't dis-/enable the indicator in application.properties using management.endpoint.aaa.enabled=true/false ...or is there a possibility to do?

Comment: Maybe using @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("app") with management.endpoint.app.enabled=true/false but this is an all or nothing approach and I can't disable selectively.

Comment: I would say it should work with the name you configure in your `application.yml`, but not sure to be honest. Never tried that.

Comment: But WHICH name? I defined it as an array. I tried it using @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator(aaa,bbb,ccc) but this din't work. Maybe you are able to find a solution!? ;-)

Comment: `@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator` does not support multiple names. At least reading the documentation seems that way: "value - The name of the health indicator.". Maybe you can use multiple `@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator` but I am not really sure that Spring supports that.

Comment: No, Spring complains about multiple usage of `@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator`. I tried already. Would be an improvement if Spring would support this. Seems as if this way of creating indicators was not considered or not wanted.