# How to test multiple instance creation of a bean of one class filled with values from application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-actuator, dynamic-properties

After creating multiple beans of a specific class using @PostConstruct according to [Multiple instances of a bean of one class filled with values from application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571749/multiple-instances-of-a-bean-of-one-class-filled-with-values-from-application-pr/69574978?noredirect=1#comment123021394_69574978)

I wonder how I could test the creation of those bean instances.

I tried it this way:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AppHealthCheckContributor.class, AppHealthCheckProperties.class})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "healthcheck")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppHealthCheckConfig.class })
//@TestPropertySource(properties = "healthcheck.app[0].name=testHealthIndicator, healthcheck.app[0].baseUrl=http://localhost, healthcheck.app[0].basePath=/test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"/application-test.properties"})
class AppHealthCheckConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private AdapterHealthCheckConfig config;

    @Test
    void healthCheckBeansAreInitialized() {
//        config.init();
        System.out.println(config.getApps().get(0));

    }
}
```

but this results in: `AppHealthCheckProperties(baseUrl=null, basePath=null, name=null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = AdapterHealthCheckConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
class AppHealthCheckConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private AdapterHealthCheckConfig config;

    @Test
    void healthCheckBeansAreInitialized() {
//        config.init();
        System.out.println(config.getApps().get(0));

    }
}
```

Comment: The first version works well. The second doesn't. This produces a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will remove the second option ;)